# Angular Response error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: json, angular, api, syntax-error, asp.net-core-webapi

I want get my data from an API. The API itself works fine in postmap like this :

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "asus g551 vw",
            "price": 500,
            "image": "https://localhost:44345/images/products/origin/img1.jpg",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "title": "asus vivobook",
            "price": 1200,
            "image": "https://localhost:44345/images/products/origin/img1.jpg",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "title": "acer predator",
            "price": 200,
            "image": "https://localhost:44345/images/products/origin/img1.jpg",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But in Angular, when I call my get function, I get an error from this Angular code :

```
myservice method 'GetUserBasketDetails()' : 

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class OrderService {
    
      
      private orderDetails : BehaviorSubject<OrderBasketDto[]> = new BehaviorSubject<OrderBasketDto[]>(null);
    
      constructor(private _http : HttpClient) { }
    
      _SetOrderDetails(details : OrderBasketDto[]){
        this.orderDetails.next(details);
        console.log(this.orderDetails)
      }
    
      _GetOrderDetails() : Observable<OrderBasketDto[]>{
        return this.orderDetails;
      }
    
    
      GetUserBasketDetails():Observable<IResponseResult<OrderBasketDto[]>>{
        return this._http.get<IResponseResult<OrderBasketDto[]>>('/basket-details');
      }
    }
```

when I call it in a component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Front-Project';

  constructor(private _accountService : AccountService,
              private _orderService : OrderService) {
  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    

    this._orderService.GetUserBasketDetails().subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      
    })

  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44345/basket-details", ok: false, …}

and

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:20175:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10720:31)
> in console

[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIMms.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're not getting the proper response from server. Try to curl the request after copying the URL.

Comment: Even though the status code is 200 OK, the response seems to be containing an error, and the `Unexpected token < in JSON` hints to the fact that the response is actually a HTML string instead of JSON.

Comment: Are you sur about your mapping IResponseResult<OrderBasketDto[]> ?. Are you try without mapping ? if you have the response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found th problem my url was wrong i forgot to add api controller name in get method
like this '/order/basket-details'